# regex: insert a break between the text and tag img

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to insert a break after any text before few or one img tag:

I have a text:

```
Some text, some text <img src="thumb.jpg" /><img src="thumb2.jpg" />
```

I would like to get:

```
Some text, some text <br /><img src="thumb.jpg" /><img src="thumb2.jpg" />
```

I would like to make it through the regular expression in Ruby using the gsub method.

Comment: Based on what you are saying shouldn't it be "Some text, some text <br /><img src="thumb.jpg" /> <br /> <img src="thumb2.jpg" />" ? Notice the second <br/> tag.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question

Comment: I think this warrants a link to the main question on these sorts of things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags. Use a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

```rb
str.gsub(/((?:<img[^>]+>)+)/, '<br />\1')
```

Depends on how you define *text*, you might need some alteration on the Regexp to make a correct substitution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should actually use `sub` instead of `gsub`, so that it only changes the first instance of the `<img>` tag that you encounter:

```
s.sub(/<img/, '<br /><img')
```